# React: invoke props in a function

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

Fairly new to React so please let me know if I'm approaching this wrong.

In short, I want to be able to redirect to the login component after a form has been submitted in the signUp component.

When we click on a signUp or login button it changes the currentPage state to the assigned value. For example if currentPage is currently set to "Login" it will load the Login component and "Sign Up" with the Sign Up component. The components load as they should but when trying to pass in the props in the SignUp component I can't figure out how to invoke the pageSetter function **after** the form has been submitted.

I could just do the below, which works but I only want to invoke it in the onSubmit function

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.pageSetter}>
```

```
import React from "react";

function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button id={props.id} value={props.value} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

```
import SignUp from "./components/signUp.jsx";
import Login from "./components/login.jsx";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    currentPage: "Login",
  };

  pageSetter = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ currentPage: target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.currentPage !== "Sign Up" && (
          <Button id={"signUp"} value={"Sign Up"} onClick={this.pageSetter} />
        )}

        {this.state.currentPage !== "Login" && (
          <Button id={"login"} value={"Login"} onClick={this.pageSetter} />
        )}

        {this.state.currentPage === "Login" && <Login />}
        {this.state.currentPage === "Sign Up" && (
          <SignUp pageSetter={this.pageSetter} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
class SignUp extends Component {

  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let attribute = event.target.id;
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ [attribute]: value });
  };

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.pageSetter.value = "Login"
    this.props.pageSetter
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <p>real_name:</p>
          <input id="real_name" type="text" onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />

          <p>username:</p>
          <input id="username" type="text" onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />

          <p>email:</p>
          <input id="email" type="text" onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />

          <p>password:</p>
          <input
            id="password"
            type="password"
            onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
          />

          <p>picture</p>
          <input id="picture" type="text" onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />

          <button id="userSubmit" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in your code example :

```
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.pageSetter.value = "Login"
    this.props.pageSetter
  };
```

Could you please edit it and i'll check again if I can help !
Also, despite the typo, I don't understand why you try to set the property "value" on the props **pageSetter** which is a **function**.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand either why you're setting a property in a function. Instead of doing this, you should invoke the function using the value as argument.

```
    this.props.pageSetter('Login');
```

You also should fix the `pageSetter` function to receive the page value instead of an event.